# Wand Image Magick interpolation

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

Does anyone know if you can use interpolation using Wand in python 3.4? 
I tried the following code. It does work as expected.

```
    img.format = 'pjpeg'
    img.delay = 10
    img.compression_quality = int(10)
    img.depth = 10
```

Any help ?